# Operator using Fourier transform

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question:

Let $\epsilon >0$. We define the operator $M:= (1-\epsilon \Delta)^{-\frac 12}$, where  $\Delta$ refers to the seconde derivative. 
Let $u \in H^2(\mathbb{T})$ (the Sobolev space of periodic functions
having $H^2$ regularity). We ask to prove the existence of  $v \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ such that  $$Mu = u + \epsilon v$$ et $\|v\|_{L^2}= \mathcal{O}(1)$

In the case where the domain of definition is $\mathbb{R}$, we can give  $Mu$ the following sense: 
$$Mu := \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big((1-\epsilon \xi^2)^{-\frac 12}\hat{u}\big).$$ But in our case, could we define $Mu$ in the sense of Fourier series? Namely,
$$Mu := \mathcal{F}^{-1}\big((1-\epsilon n^2)^{-\frac 12}\hat{u}(n)\big).$$
Thank you.

Comment: the Fourier series can be viewed as the discretization in the frequency domain of the function we would have obtained by  restricting the function to one period and taking its Fourier transform. so the answer is yes, we can define the operator as a multiplication of the Fourier series coefficients. and I  didn't get what is $v$

Comment: In fact, as in the Taylor's series, we write formally
$$(1-\epsilon \Delta)^{-\frac 12}= 1+ \frac 12 \epsilon \Delta + R(\epsilon, \Delta).$$
 I just want to prove that we can do this development on $Mu$.

Comment: so the result of Fourier inversion should be $L^2(\mathbb{T})$ when $\hat{u}(n) = \mathcal{O}(n^{-1-\epsilon})$

Comment: Yes. That's why we assume that $u \in H^2(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: and to estimate to norm of the residual $v$ I would go again to the Fourier domain, as $H^2(\mathbb{T})$ has a simple meaning there.

Comment: do you agree that if $\mathcal{F}^{-1}((1-\epsilon n^2)^{-1/2} \hat{u}(n))$ exists then it has to be $Mu$ ? and you know it exists and $\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ because you supposed that $u \in H^2(\mathbb{T})$, CQFD ?

Comment: Well I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Spectral Theory for selfadjoint operators gives you a way to view functions of a selfadjoint operator $A$ as multiplication operators on the spectrum. For example,
$$
           F(-\Delta)f = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{F(-s^2)\mathcal{F}\{f\}\}.
$$
Specifically,
$$
        (I-\epsilon\Delta)^{-1}f=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{(1+\epsilon s^2)^{-1}\mathcal{F}\{f\}\}.
$$
The reason for $-s^2$ instead of $s$ is that the Fourier transform is built for the operator $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ so that $s^2$ is associated with $\frac{1}{i^2}\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$.

When you're working on the unit circle (or, equivalently, periodic functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$,) the spectrum is discrete. When you treat the spectrum $\sigma(\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{d\theta})=\mathbb{Z}$ as a discrete space with counting measure, then $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{d\theta}$ is transformed to multiplication by $s$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.

The continuous Fourier transform confuses things because the underlying space and the spectral space are the same, and the spectral density measure is uniform. The discrete case better represents what is going on. The space is continuous, but the spectrum is discrete. The spectral density measure remains uniform, but that's to be expected for differentiation.  Other operators may require non-uniform spectral density measures.

Comment: Thank you very much. Would you please add a link fo a book where I could find more details about that ?

Comment: @A.MONET : This is the multiplication form of the Spectral Theorem for selfadjoint linear operators on a Hilbert Space. Here's a PDF with a full-blown proof: http from Michael Taylor's website: //www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/specthm.pdf . Michael Taylor is a Professor of Mathematics at UNC. The first part of page 6 gives the first version of such a theorem, and follows up with the full version (with proof.) I'm afraid this is not a simple theorem for the general case.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll check it. It seems to be "not difficult"